# Ubuntu 20.04 packages for passenger and ruby

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, nginx, ruby

Phusion Passenger makes their binaries available via this repo https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger

When I install libnginx-mod-http-passenger via apt-get, it will automatically install ruby 2.7. In digging around, I found that a call to `apt show passenger` also shows that dependency could optionally be satisfied by ruby3.0, ruby3.1 or ruby3.2, however I don't see those packages available for install anywhere. Do those packages exist and if so, how do I access them?

```
Package: passenger Version: 1:6.0.18-1~focal1 Priority: optional Section: ruby Maintainer: Phusion <info@phusion.nl> Installed-Size:
11.8 MB Provides: ruby-passenger Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28), libcrypt1 (>= 1:4.1.0), libcurl4 (>= 7.16.2), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libpcre3, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), procps, ruby3.2 | ruby3.1 | ruby3.0 | ruby2.7 | ruby2.6 | ruby2.5 | ruby2.4 | ruby2.3 | ruby2.2 | ruby2.1 | ruby2.0 | ruby1.9.1 | ruby1.8 | ruby-interpreter, rubygems-integration (>= 1.8) | rubygems1.9.1 | rubygems1.9 | rubygems (>= 1.2), ruby-rack Recommends: passenger-doc (= 1:6.0.18-1~focal1), passenger-dev (= 1:6.0.18-1~focal1) Breaks: libapache2-mod-passenger (<< 1:6.0.18), libnginx-mod-http-passenger (<< 1:6.0.18), passenger-common, passenger-common1.8, passenger-common1.9.1, ruby-passenger Replaces: libapache2-mod-passenger (<< 1:6.0.18), libnginx-mod-http-passenger (<< 1:6.0.18), passenger-common, passenger-common1.8, passenger-common1.9.1, ruby-passenger Homepage: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/ Download-Size: 2391 kB APT-Manual-Installed: no APT-Sources: https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger focal/main amd64 Packages Description: Application server for Ruby, Node.js, Python, Meteor  Passenger makes deployment of web apps very easy and robust.  It can be used standalone or integrated with Nginx or Apache. Passenger is a Phusion product.

N: There are 14 additional records. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

Comment: Do `apt policy ruby3.0` , `apt policy ruby3.1` and `apt policy ruby3.2` and see which packages have candidates for your system.

Comment: Thanks @Jos, looks like there are no candidates for those 3--does that mean they are just placeholders, or does it suggest that those packages do exist somewhere else, and if so, how would one find the system they are available on? Separately, if I install ruby 3 manually, is there a way for me to somehow force the package manager to use that version vs installing the available candidate?

Comment: On my (23.04) system `ruby3.1` is  an installable candidate. The other two packages are not known to exist (to the package manager). `ruby3.1` is not compatible with your current 20.04 system, not even when also installing dependencies. To install it you would need to upgrade your 20.04 Ubuntu to a more recent one. Which one? You can find that out here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ruby3.1. There is no LTS version where Ruby 3.1 is available, but it is installable on 22.10 and 23.04. Ruby 3.0 is available on 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is a bit over three years old. So it is compatible with three-year-old releases of ruby. For newer releases of ruby, run a newer release of Ubuntu.